# VS 2015 - WP8.1 Task Scheduler on **Non** Silverlight project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm building an app for Windows Phone 8.1 (Not Universal yet due to lack of AdMob support), and I need to create a new Task Scheduler, but all tutorials, videos, SO questions point to a **Visual C# > Windows Phone > Windows Phone Scheduled Task Agent**, but on VS 2015 community, I find only **Visual C# > Windows Phone > *Scheduled Task Agent (Windows Phone Silverlight)***.

My question: Are they the same? If so, why the "Silverlight" tag?

Sorry, but everywhere Google takes me, either it has no mention to Silverlight, mentioning the option that doesn't exist on my VS, or are questions about how silverlight won't work anymore on WP8.1 and how to fix it...

Comment: Well, for starters, is your app using Silverlight or WinRT? One way to find out is creating a page, and see from what class it inherits (see the full namespace by hovering the mouse on "Page"). If it's `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Page` then it's a Silverlight project. If it's `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` then it's a WinRT project

Comment: WinRT... Sorry if my question was unclear about it...

Comment: Hey, could you solve the problem? same happend to me and I dont know what to do